Does this part listed on Bricklink really exist? White 4774c01 Electric, Sound Siren 9V 2 x 2 x 1 1/3 with Two Town Police / Fire Noises

This part: White 4774c01 Electric, Sound Siren 9V 2 x 2 x 1 1/3 with Two Town Police / Fire Noises appears in the Bricklink catalog. It is visually identical to this part: White 4774c02 Electric, Sound Siren 9V 2 x 2 x 1 1/3 with 2 Space Noises.
When connected to 9v the difference between the two parts is apparent in that the former produces town fire/police noises and the latter produces space noises.
The sounds can be heard online here and here.
I have never managed to find a white 4774c01 and every one I have bought from Bricklink has turned out to be a mis-listed 4774c02 and every answered enquiry to sellers listing a white 4774c01 has resulted in them confirming an incorrect listing.
A while ago Bricklink used to list set 6483 as containing a white 4774c01 but the listing was changed to a white 4774c02. It would seem to make more sense for town sets to include 4774c01 with town sounds vs 4774c02 with space sounds.
Sets 6483 and 6482 are both town sets but are listed as containing white 4774c02 parts with space sounds.
Does anyone have a 6483 or 6482 set they have had since new and can confirm which type of 4774c0x was included?
Or does anyone own a verified white 4774c01 and can confirm that the part actually exists?

The video review of the 6483 set made by madaboutlego shows that this set did indeed make the space sounds and not the town ones. See https://youtube.com/watch?v=tDTQkA_4O7I from about 1:55.

@zovits Thanks for the link. While he does have the box, the condition of the parts looked quite used in the closeups so I am skeptical as to if all of the parts are original. I would love to see an unboxing but given the age of the sets it is unlikely.

There are sealed sets for sale on BrickLink (but they are a bit expensive) so you could buy those and do an unboxing.

@Henriksupportsthecommunity I am aware, but I already own both of the sets. I was hoping someone on here could solve the riddle without spending hundreds for sets I already own.

To answer your question, I do not actually own a set containing this piece, but if you look up "Lego coastal patrol set" on YouTube, there is a video where the guy talks about that piece - so I presume that it is indeed a real piece.

Do you have a link to the video? Because if you are referring to this one from JangBricks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bw50I0t3n8U then the part he has is the one with space noises (4774c02). See links in my original question for sound samples. Also, it looks like he pieced the set together as he is missing the radar printed tile, so I think that video is inconclusive.
